# May need an appropriate loader to handle this file type...happening on every vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, yarnpkg

I have a project which has a rails backend a Vue frontend. I have everything working between the two ends, and now I'm trying to add Vuetify to make it look nicer.

I ran `vue install vuetify` and got

```
Running completion hooks... ERROR  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './draw-front/public/index.html'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './draw-front/public/index.html'
```

So, instead I tried adding manually via the guide [on the vuetify website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#webpack-install), but whichever method I use I get errors that there is no appropriate handler for the components

```
  error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCombobox/VCombobox.js

 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (69:44)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
 | 
 |       if (this.multiple) {
 |         chip.componentOptions.listeners = { ...chip.componentOptions.listeners,
 |           dblclick: () => {
 |             this.editingIndex = index;

  @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCombobox/index.js 1:0-36
  @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
  @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
  @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
  @ ./src/main.js
  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5106 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

There are similar errors for about 20 different components, and in the browser I just get `Cannot GET /`

Versions: 
@vue/cli 4.1.2
Rails 6.0.2.1
ruby 2.6.5p114

Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "sinon": "^4.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What year did you create your Vue.js project? Your package.json look like old and Vuetify Installation need your project updated.

I recommend that you create a new project with Vue CLI (with last version), install Vuetify and then migrate your files from the old project for the new project.

It's seems a hard work, but is very simple.

Use also the last version of Node.js.

Comment: I created it last week. What particular elements look old?

Comment: Many packages that are in your devDependencies can't be there.

E.g. "babel-loaders" must be encapsulated in "@vue/cli-plugin-babel". See more about this in link: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/

Other thing, the correct package of Vue CLI is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli

- You can't use this version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli

Comment: The "@" version is the version that I have  `vue --version`
`@vue/cli 4.1.2`

Comment: I did a fresh run, but this time instead of doing `vue init webpack {frontend_dir}`  as per https://web-crunch.com/ruby-on-rails-api-vue-js/, I just did `vue create {frontend_dir}` (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#vue-cli-install) and chose NPM instead of Yarn, and everything seems to be working fine now

Comment: When you run "vue init webpack...", you run the legacy way. The right way is "vue create...". See more in this link: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#pulling-2-x-templates-legacy

Comment: Ah, makes sense. And does choosing npm or yarn make much of a difference?

Comment: I use NPM, but there aren't differences.